# Implicit differentiation of a two variables function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

A function $z=z(x,y)$ is given implicitly by the function
$$f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{x^{\lambda}}\right)=0$$
where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R},\lambda\neq0$.

I have to show that if $f(u,v)$ is differentiable and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u,v)\neq0$$
then
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\lambda z$$

I tried to do this using the Implict function theorem:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\displaystyle\dfrac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}$$
So calling
$$F(x,y)=f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{x^{\lambda}}\right)$$
and applying the chain rule, I got:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$
so
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{1}{y}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}$$
But I don't know if is this the right way and, if it really is, what I'm supposed to do from now on?

I did all this trying to find some expression to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, but I don't know if it worked.

Comment: Some observations: (i) You should use the fact that $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$ [currently you are ignoring that fact], (ii) It is better to write "$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$" rather than "$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$" to avoid confusion and to be consistent with the notation of the question [in particular, your $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ is not quite correct], (iii) you forgot that differentiating $zx^{-\lambda}$ with respect to $x$ must use the product rule and that is where you get derivatives of $z$ in the picture.  Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the formula "$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial f/ \partial x}{\partial f/\partial z}$" (I'm not sure what $\partial f /\partial x$ is even intended to mean).

Comment: @Michael I fixed it, but does it equal to 0 (the last expression)?

Comment: I do not understand your comment above.  What did you fix?  What equals 0?  If you can solve your own question now, one method is to answer your own question below.

Comment: I don't know what to do.

Comment: Well, for example, you have $F(x,y) = f(u(x,y), v(x,y))$ and so $$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$  This is what I meant in my comments (ii) and (iii) above.  You can also take derivatives with respect to $y$.  On the other hand, you also know $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$, which is the same as my comment (i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv=0$$
where
$$du=d(x/y)=\frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy$$
$$dv=d(z/x^\lambda)=\frac{1}{x^\lambda}dz-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}dx$$
We know that
$$dz=\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}dy$$
So
$$dv=d(z/x^\lambda)=\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}dy-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}dx$$
Now $df$ becomes
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\bigg( \frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy\bigg)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}dy-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}dx \bigg)=0$$
This equation is always satisfied when
$$\frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy=0$$
$$\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}dy-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}dx=0$$
From the first condition it follows that
$$dy=\frac{y}{x}dx$$
Replacing this into the second condition
$$\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}dx+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}\frac{y}{x}dx-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}dx=0$$
$$\bigg(\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}\frac{y}{x}-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}\bigg)dx=0$$
$$\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{x^\lambda}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}\frac{y}{x}-\frac{\lambda z}{x^{\lambda+1}}=0$$
$$x\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y}=\lambda z$$